# Matlab's subs does not evaluate symbolic Bessel function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I experienced a strange behaviour in Matlab with the function `subs` and the built-in `besselj`:

```
syms x
f = besselj(1,x)
subs(f,1)
```

returns

```
besselj(1, 1)
```

even though the documentation states

> "`subs(s,new)` returns a copy of `s` replacing all occurrences of the default variable in `s` with new, **and then evaluating `s`**.

The default variable is defined by symvar.

So I would expect the output of `subs(f,1)` to be `0.4401`. `eval(subs(f,1))` produces the correct output of `0.4401`. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you're trying to define an [anonymous function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), you don't need `subs` or `eval` here, simply use `f` as an actual function...

```
% No need to use symbolic math toolbox for x or f 
f = @(x) besselj(1,x);  % Define f as an anonymous function of x
f(1)                    % Evaulate f at a given point, say x = 1
>> ans = 0.4401
```

---

Side note: If for some reason you're really set on using symbolic variables (they seem overkill here) then you may just want to use the `eval` function and a symbolic function handle instead of `subs`.

```
syms f(x)            % Defines f as a symfun and x as a sym variable
f(x) = besselj(1,x); % Define the function
eval(f(1))           % Evaluate at x=1
>> ans = 0.4401
```

---

In answer to your question about why `subs` doesn't "evaluate" the answer when using `subs(f, 1)`... It's probably because the nature of the `besselj` function. Because you're using symvars, you are using the symbolic math package's `besselj` function (as opposed to the core-package function by the same name).

This means that a symbolic expression is displayed to the command window when `subs` is used, in the same way that any other symbolic expression is displayed without needing to be evaluated - i.e. they can be *simplified* but don't run other functions.

This is why you then need to run `eval`, to *evaluate* the simplified symbolic expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using symbolic variables, because I am letting Matlab obtain their derivatives for me. Thanks for pointing out that I can actually use a symbolic function handle.

Comment: No worries, glad this answered your question :)